# Numerical Approximation of erfc

Tags: numerics, special-functions

[image]

I have a crazy output. I already tried the N[] function. All it does is condense the inputs. Any idea of how to have a numerical output from the code?

Comment: Please provide actual code rather than an image of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dist = NormalDistribution[a, b];

$Assumptions = DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist]

(* a ∈ Reals && b > 0 *)

cdf[q_] = CDF[dist, q];
```

If I have read your expression properly, it can be written more compactly as

```
expr1 = (4*(cdf[1] - cdf[0]) + 6*(cdf[2] - cdf[1]) +
      8*(cdf[3] - cdf[2]) + 10*(cdf[4] - cdf[3]) +
      12*(cdf[5] - cdf[4]))/(cdf[5] - cdf[0]) // FullSimplify;
```

And even more so as

```
expr2 = Total[
    2 (# + 1)*(cdf[#] - cdf[# - 1]) & /@ Range[5]]/(cdf[5] - cdf[0]) // 
  FullSimplify

(* (2 (-6 Erf[(-5 + a)/(Sqrt[2] b)] + Erf[(-4 + a)/(Sqrt[2] b)] + 
     Erf[(-3 + a)/(Sqrt[2] b)] + Erf[(-2 + a)/(Sqrt[2] b)] + 
     Erf[(-1 + a)/(Sqrt[2] b)] + 2 Erf[a/(Sqrt[2] b)]))/(-1 + 
   Erf[a/(Sqrt[2] b)] + Erfc[(-5 + a)/(Sqrt[2] b)]) *)
```

Verifying that `expr1` and `expr2` are identical

```
expr1 === expr2

(* True *)
```

Using your assignments

```
a = (1/2*Erfc[1/Sqrt[2]]*x); 
b = -q*Log[2, q] - (1 - q)*Log[2, 1 - q];
q = a/x;
x = 4;

expr2 // N

(* 4.70403 *)
```